# basic resursion que of string

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings, function-definition

i have some set of rules to create a string in a char array

```
a. The string begins with an 'a'
b. Each 'a' is followed by nothing or an 'a' or "bb"
c. Each "bb" is followed by nothing or an 'a'
```

my code is:-

```c
    bool checkAB(char input[]) {
        if(input[0]=='\0'){
            return true;
        }
        if(input[0]!='a'){
            return false;
        }
        bool ans=checkAB(input+1);
        if(input[0]=='a'){
            if(input[1]=='a' || (input[1]=='b' && input[2]=='b') || input[1]==' ')
                return ans && true;
    
            if(input[1]=='b' && input[2]=='b'){
                if(input[3]==' ' || input[3]=='a'){
                    return ans && true;
                }
            }
        }
    
        
        return false;
    }
```

this code doesn't pass all the test case. can anyone help.
pls use recursive approch

Comment: It looks like homework. Is it? Read this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: `input[1]==' '` tests for a space. A space is not nothing. Show the original problem statement.

Comment: `bool ans=checkAB(input+1);` attempts to check the input in a recursive way, but it is followed by code that also checks the input. This code just is not structured correctly, and correcting it is not a simple matter of fixing minor bugs. Likely, the code should be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: `if(input[0]=='\0'){ return true; }` causes the function to accept an empty string as valid. However, rule a. says the string must start with an “a”, and an empty string does not start with an “a”. Show the original problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happen when call with "abb"

The first call will execute this line:

```
bool ans=checkAB(input+1);
```

which means that we call the function with the input "bb"

That will return FALSE (due to `if(input[0]!='a')`).

So back in the first call we set `ans` to FALSE and consequently we end up returning FALSE.

I would think that **before** the recursive call, you should remove any "bb" following an 'a'.

Something like:

```
bool checkAB(const char input[]) 
{
    if(input[0] != 'a') return false;   // input must start with an 'a'

    if (input[1] == '\0') return true;  // input was "a"

    if (input[1] == 'b' && input[2] == 'b')
    {
        if (input[3] == '\0') return true;   // input was "abb"
        
        return checkAB(input+3);  // Call without leading "abb"
    }

    return checkAB(input+1);  // Call without leading "a"
}
```

or you can use `strcmp` like:

```
bool checkAB(const char input[]) 
{
    if (input[0] != 'a') return false;
    
    if (strcmp(input, "a") == 0) return true;
    if (strcmp(input, "abb") == 0) return true;

    if (input[1] == 'b' && input[2] == 'b') return checkAB(input+3);  // Call without leading "abb"

    return checkAB(input+1);  // Call without leading "a"
}
```

Comment: can you explain this if (input[1] != 'b' || input[2] != 'b'){
        return false;
    }

Comment: @KishanRaj It check for two consecutive `b`

Comment: @KishanRaj I updated the answer to a more readable form. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not being changed within the function

```
bool checkAB( const char input[]) {
```

An empty string does not satisfy the requirements. So this if statement

```
    if(input[0]=='\0'){
        return true;
    }
```

is incorrect.

As a result this call

```
bool ans=checkAB(input+1);
```

can set the variable `ans` to false for example when the source string is `"a"`. In this case the function returns false.

Also it is unclear why you are comparing an element of the string with the space character

```
 if(input[1]=='a' || (input[1]=='b' && input[2]=='b') || input[1]==' ')
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool checkAB( const char *s ) 
{
    return  *s == 'a' && 
            ( *++s == '\0' || 
              ( *s == 'a' && checkAB( s ) ) ||
              ( *s == 'b' && *++s == 'b' && ( ( *++s == '\0' ) || ( *s == 'a' && checkAB( s ) ) ) ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "a";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %s\n", s, checkAB( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "aa";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %s\n", s, checkAB( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "abb";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %s\n", s, checkAB( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "aaa";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %s\n", s, checkAB( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "abba";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %s\n", s, checkAB( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"a" -> true
"aa" -> true
"abb" -> true
"aaa" -> true
"abba" -> true
```

Comment: `*s == 'a' && checkAB( s )` is redundant; `checkAB(s)` suffices. The test cases do not include any for which the string does not satisfy the rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, it is not redundant. The pointer s was incremented before this condition.

Comment: It is redundant because `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` is true if and only if `checkAB(s)` is true. Whether `s` was incremented previously is irrelevant; the issue involved is not whether `*s == 'a'` or `checkAB(s)` is affected by any previous character `s` was pointing to but what their values are with the current `s`. `checkAB(s)` evaluates to true only if `*s == 'a'` is true, since that is the first code in it, so `checkAB(s)` can never differ from `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If just to write checkAB( s ) then teh function can be called for a string that starts with "bb". In this case this call returns false.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, and false is the result you want when `checkAB(s)` is called with `s` pointing to “bb”. If, after `*++s == '\0'`, we call `checkAB(s)` with `s` pointing to “bb”, then `checkAB` will return false, and the code will proceed with the `||` and evaluate `*s == 'b' &&…` and get the desired result.

Comment: As a matter of simple logic, `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` is mathematically equivalent to `checkAB(s)`. There is nothing `s` can point to that causes `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` to be true when `checkAB(s)` is false or that causes `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` to be false when `checkAB(s)` is true.

Comment: Proof: If `*s` is `'a'`, then `*s == 'a'` is true, so the value of the `&&` is determined by the right operand, so the value of `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` is the value of `checkAB(s)`. If `*s == 'a'` is false, the value of `&&` is zero, and, given that `*s == 'a'` is false, `checkAB(s)` returns zero (because its code is `return  *s == 'a' &&…`), so `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` and `checkAB(s)` have the same value.

Comment: Or put another way, `checkAB(s)` implies `*s == 'a'`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This call can be redundant in the case when *s != 'a'

Comment: `checkAB(s)` is equivalent to `*s == 'a' && OTHERSTUFF`, so `*s == 'a' && checkAB(s)` is equivalent to `*s == 'a' && *s == 'a' && OTHERSTUFF`. The initial `*s == 'a' &&` is redundant (since it has no required side-effects).

Comment: @IanAbbott But this requires one more recursive call. The less recursion calls the better.

Comment: But also, the fewer redundant comparison operations the better.

Comment: @IanAbbott Compared with the number of recursive calls it is a wrong resume.

Comment: The shortest I can get it is `return *s == 'a' && (*++s != 'b' || (++s, *s++ == 'b')) && (*s == '\0' || checkAB(s));`.